# expanding a row by splitting it into existing columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split, reshape

I have read tables from pdf using tabula-py command with the following code:

`table = tabula.read_pdf(files[0],pages = 'all',multiple_tables = True,  stream = True)`

Sometimes values from two columns are joined into a single column(separated by single space). For example:

| col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 c1 | d1 | e1 f1 | g1 | h1 | NA | NA |
| a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 | e2 | f2 | g2 | h2 |

How can i readjust the values into the correct columns, to get:

| col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 | e1 | f1 | g1 | h1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 | e2 | f2 | g2 | h2 |

Answer (score 2):

- output as space delimited
- replace quoted strings from step 1
- read back as space delimited

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""col0    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7
a1  b1 c1   d1  e1 f1   g1  h1  NA  NA
a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  f2  g2  h2"""), sep="\t")

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df.to_csv(sep=" ").replace("\"", "")), sep="\s+")
```

### output

```
col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
  a1   b1   c1   d1   e1   f1   g1   h1
  a2   b2   c2   d2   e2   f2   g2   h2
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
table = tabula.read_pdf(files[0],pages = 'all',multiple_tables = True,guess = False, stream = True)
```